# How to export SourceForge mailing list messages to mbox format

Tags: sourceforge

SourceForge hosts mailing list, but can I export the messages to mbox format for migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export any SourceForge mailing list to 'mbox' format by visiting:

```
https://lists.sourceforge.net/mbox/LISTNAME
```

This requires authentication via SourceForge before you can proceed. 
More information at https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Mailing%20List%20Archives/

Smaller mailing list archives tend to be easily downloadable from any web browser. Larger mailing list archives may timeout, but I've had success still downloading them via commandline tools like `wget`

Comment: For any non-administrators looking for this, SourceForge [says](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Mailing%20List%20Archives/), "[W]e make these archive files available solely to project administrators."